# After closing showDatePicker Barrier not closing in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, datepicker, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have started using flutter bloc recently. I am facing some problems with showDatePicker. After some research I learned that snackbar and dialog should display inside listener. But I don't understand to implement this functions correctly. Thats why I need some help:

this is my event class:

```
class DatePickerEvent extends CollectionEvent {

  DateTime? startDate, endDate;
  final bool isStartDate;

  DatePickerEvent({ this.startDate, this.endDate, required this.isStartDate});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [startDate, endDate, isStartDate];

}
```

this is my state class:

```
class PickDateState  extends CollectionState {

  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime endDate;

  const PickDateState({required this.startDate, required this.endDate});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [startDate, endDate];

}
```

this is my bloc class:

```
    on<DatePickerEvent>((event, emit) async {
    
          emit(PickDateState(startDate: event.startDate ?? DateTime.now(), endDate: event.endDate ?? DateTime.now()));
        });
```

this is my datePick Function:

```
Future _pickDates(BuildContext context, {required bool isStartDate}) async {
    var initialDate = DateTime.now();

    if (isStartDate && _startDate != null) {
      initialDate = _startDate!;
    } else if (!isStartDate && _endDate != null) {
      initialDate = _endDate!;
    }

    final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: initialDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1990),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      helpText: AppLocalization.of(context).getTranslatedValue(isStartDate ? 'start_date' : 'end_date'),
      fieldHintText: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    );

    if(!mounted) return;
    if (pickedDate != null) {
      if (isStartDate) {
        _startDate = pickedDate;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {

          context.read<CollectionBloc>().add(DatePickerEvent(isStartDate: true, startDate: pickedDate));
        });
      } else {
        // _endDate = pickedDate;
        context.read<CollectionBloc>().add(DatePickerEvent(isStartDate: false, endDate: pickedDate));
      }
    }

  }
```

this is where I called the function:

```
ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: kSecondaryPrimaryColor),
                child: Text(_startDate == null ? "start_date" : DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_startDate!),
                onPressed: () {
                  _pickDates(context, isStartDate: true);
                },
              ),

              return const SizedBox();
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

See `BlocBuilder` gives you constant states. like a stream and need a returning widgets where you add some constraints for states and return widgets accordingly. here you don't do things like `navigating` to other screen, showing `snackBar` and `dialogs` cause it gets called constantly, even without change in state.

Where as `BlocListener` is called only when the state is changed. And here you don't get to return a widget, you just define a `child` here which don't get changed any time.

And there's a BlocConsumer too, which holds functionality of both `BlocBuilder` and `BlocListener` here you get `builder` and `listener` both.

You can use any one of the three as per your convince and your use-case, you can use `BlocListener` if you just want to show the button and on clicking it you show the `datePicker` and want to show some `snackBar` or `Dialog` or `Navigating` to other page.

Or you can use `BlocBuilder` if you want to show other widget in place of button on different state, when you are in loading state (when your datePicker is in focus); you can show a Loading widgets like `CircularProgressIndicator`. Or you can have the functionality of both `builder` and `listener` with `BlocConsumer`.